# Convert KeyValuePair ForEach to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, foreach

I have the following `KeyValuePair` in `Dictionary<string,string>` format.

As it will always be parsed in as 1 pair, the `foreach` is not required. However, I am unable to remove it without causing an error in the syntax.

May I know if the `foreach` can be removed, and also be converted to `LINQ` syntax?

```
string key = "";
string value = "";

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in pairing)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",
        kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Confused: you only ever have one KVP in the dictionary? So why do you have a dictionary at all?

Comment: "As it will always be parsed in as 1 pair, the `foreach` is not required." - what do you mean by this? You **need** a `foreach` to actually enumerate over any `IEnumerable<T>` - it's just that Linq comes with a few convenience methods like `ToList`, `ToArray` and `ToDictionary` that hide the `foreach` - but it's still there.

Comment: Also, what are you **actually** trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a `List` of `Dictionary` `(List<Dictionary<string, string>>)`, and each `Dictionary` only contains 1 pair. I guess I utilized the function wrongly :(

Comment: As I only have one paring in each Dictionary, I want to fetch the `Key` and `Value` out from the dictionary and assign to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a List of Dictionary (`List<Dictionary<string, string>>`), and each Dictionary only contains 1 pair.

You'll need to write your own extension-method if you want something more succinct. The method below also converts the *legacy* `KeyValuePair<K,V>` struct to a `ValueTuple<K,V>` which is more useful due to destructuring:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static ( TKey key, TValue value ) UnwrapSingle<TKey,TValue>( this IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue> dict )
    {
        var kvp = dict.Single();
        return ( kvp.Key, kep.Value );
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
( String key, String value ) = paring.UnwrapSingle();
Console.WriteLine( key );
Console.WriteLine( value );
```

---

I just saw your remark that it's actually a `List< Dictionary<K,V> >`, in which case you can still use `UnwrapSingle`, like so:

```
List< Dictionary<String,String> > listOfSingleElementDictionaries = ...

foreach( Dictionary<String,String> dict in listOfSingleElementDictionaries )
{
    ( String key, String value ) = paring.UnwrapSingle();
    Console.WriteLine( key );
    Console.WriteLine( value );
}
```

If you want to flatten them all to a single output `Dictionary<String,String>`, then you can do that in 3 lines:

```
Dictionary<String,String> output = listOfSingleElementDictionaries
    .Select( d => d.UnwrapSingle() )
    .ToDictionary( t => t.key, t => t.value );
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I used the extension method of `UnwrapSingle` at the end. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one pair in the dictionary like `Dictionary<string, string> paring = new Dictionary<string, string>();` then you can implement below code,

```
var result = paring.ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
var key = result.Single().Key;
var value = result.Single().Value;
```

and if you have list of dictionary with one pair like `List<Dictionary<string, string>> listOfDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();` then you can do this,

```
var result = listOfDictionary.ToDictionary(s => s.Keys.Single(), s => s.Values.Single());
```

When you have huge amount of data in the list of dictionary then this way you can optimize the performance.